# django cache - f5 reload

Tags: django, caching

I am caching some heavy queries like this:

```
def news(request):
  if cache.get('allnews','expired') == 'expired':
      allnews = NewsModel.objects.order_by('-pubdate')[:10]
      cache.set('allnews', allnews, 60*10)
  else:
      allnews = cache.get('allnews')
  return render(request, 'news.html', {'allnews':allnews})
```

it is fantastic how it works! but it is still calculating the query if i reload the page with <kbd>F5</kbd>

why is it? I thought it gets from cache since I cached the queryset for 10 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried to verify `if 'allnews' in cache` instead `if cache.get('allnews','expired') == 'expired'?`

Comment: @brunozrk yes, tried that, but it is still calculating the query anew

Comment: What happens, after `cache.set`, if you call this code `cache.get('allnews')`. Im trying to understand your problem. It can be in the condition or the cache really is not caching the value

Comment: @brunozrk you are right. if I do ``print cache.get('allnews')`` right after ``.set()``, i am getting ``None``. why is this? I am setting correctly, right?

Comment: Your memcached service is starded? `service memcached start`

Comment: @brunozrk oh, i didnot started yet , dang it :D. i am in windows in dev, how can I start it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60695/discussion-between-brunozrk-and-doniyor).